# How can we represent the word "Action" with an Icon

Tags: icons, design, actions

I personally think that "Action" itself represents all other actions. Since it's so vague, there can't be a representation.

But this is needed, to be used in a tooling application UI. Please help with a design or a suggestion.

Comment: Could you give a little more of context?

Comment: Icon requests are not normally allowed here so this question might be put on hold (see the tour under Help). Enter "Actions" into https://www.iconfinder.com and you will see a few which might meet your needs.

Comment: Borderline. The question of whether or not it can/should be represented by an icon is on-topic, although we'd need more context in order to have that discussion. The question of what icon should be used, if any, would be off-topic.

Answer (score 1):

first, can you describe what this icon does in a sentence?
can you describe what will happen when you click it?
can you give additional meanings to this Icon?
sometimes it's easier to define a word in an icon by explaining it to yourself(that's also true for copywriting).
 As you said it's vague and can have many meanings, so try to find your aim.
 Also, you can search icon sites like https://www.iconfinder.com/, search for action, and find other descriptive wards for similar icons, this technic might get you closer to your goal.